# How do I set up Travis for non-package code?

Tags: r, travis-ci

I would like to set up Travis CI for an R project hosted on Github that *isn’t a package*. Unfortunately, the official R Travis support seems to be pretty hard-wired to packages (which, to be fair, makes sense).

Is there any chance to get this working for non-package code, or is my only recourse to branch [r-travis](https://github.com/craigcitro/r-travis) and patch it according to my specifications? I don’t feel competent enough to do this easily.

Here’s my failing Travis configuration:

```
language: R

r_github_packages:
    - klmr/modules

r_binary_packages:
    - testthat

script: make test
```

This fails with the following error:

> The command `"Rscript -e 'deps <- devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'"` failed and exited with 1 during .

This makes sense: `devtools::install_deps` only works in the context of a package.

I’ve tried suppressing the installation step, by adding `install: true` to my configuration. However, now the dependencies are no longer installed, and the build consequently fails with

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘modules’

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that a naïve approach is fairly easy; the following (*complete* `.travis.yml`) works for my purposes:

```
language: R

install:
    - Rscript -e 'install.packages(c("devtools", "testthat"))'
    - Rscript -e 'devtools::install_github("klmr/modules")'

script: make test
```

However, I’d still prefer a solution that can actually use the Travis declarations (`r_binary_packages`, etc.) instead of having to install dependencies manually.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for an even more basic setup to get started. Here is what worked well for me.

- `.travis.yml`:

  ```
  language: r

  install:
      - Rscript install_packages.R

  script:
      - Rscript testthat.R
  ```
- `install_packages.R`:

  ```
  install.packages('testthat')
  ```
- `testthat.R`:

  ```
  library(testthat)

  test_that('blabla', {
    expect_equal(1+2, 3)
  })
  ```